# Return x-amount of divs depending on list size

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that roughly looks something like this:

```js
import cx from 'clsx';

const myComponent = () => {
  function myFunc(binaryList) {
    for (const binaryVal of binaryList) {
      if (binaryVal == 1) {
        return <div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>;
      } else if (binaryVal == 0) {
        return <div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>;
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
      <div className={styles.listClass}>{myFunc(myBinaryList)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default myComponent;
```

Basically, I get a list (`myBinaryList`) from somewhere, which I input into the function `myFunc`. This list can have different lengths, but consists of 1's and 0's, so something like:

```
myBinaryList = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

What I would like to do is do take this list `myBinaryList`, use it in the function `myFunc`, and then it should output the same number of divs as the length of the list. So basically the output of this list should be:

```
<div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>
<div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>
```

But right now I only get one div as output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the return statement in the `myFunc` breaks the loop so it return only the first div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return an array of divs. Now your myFunc function is returning only a div. Try doing it with map.

```
 function myFunc(binaryList) {
   return binaryList.map(binaryVal => {
     if (binaryVal == 1) {
       return <div className={cx(styles.all, styles.special)}></div>
     } else if (binaryVal == 0) {
       return <div className={cx(styles.all)}></div>
     }
   });
 }
```